# Tic-tac-toe game is not completing

Tags: visual-c++

I'm making tic-tac-toe game n here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void drawBoard();
void startGame();
char turn;
char turn1;
char board[9] = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8' };
void main()
{
    cout << endl << "                          *** TIC-TAC-TOE ***" << endl
        << "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "**Start the game please**\n" << endl;
    cout << "\t\t\tPlayer 1 <x> - Player 2 <0>" << endl << endl;
    drawBoard();
    startGame();
    system("pause");
}
void drawBoard()
{
    cout << "The playing board is here for you!!" << endl << endl;
    cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
    cout << "  " << board[0] << "  |  " << board[1] << "  |  " << board[2] << endl;
    cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
    cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
    cout << "  " << board[3] << "  |  " << board[4] << "  |  " << board[5] << endl;
    cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
    cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
    cout << "  " << board[6] << "  |  " << board[7] << "  |  " << board[8] << endl;
    cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
}
void startGame()
{
        int choice;
        int cell = 0;
        for (int i=1; i <= 4; i++)
        {
            turn = 'x';
            if (turn == 'x')
            {
                cout << "Player's 1 turn [x]: ";
            }
            else if (turn == '0')
            {
                cout << "Player's 2 turn [0]: ";
            }
            cin >> choice;
            cout << "enter the cell number: ";
            cin >> cell;
            if (choice == 0 && board[cell] == '0')
            {
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
                cout << "  " << turn << "  |  " << board[1] << "  |  " << board[2] << endl;
                cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
                cout << "  " << board[3] << "  |  " << board[4] << "  |  " << board[5] << endl;
                cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
                cout << "  " << board[6] << "  |  " << board[7] << "  |  " << board[8] << endl;
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
            }
            else if (choice == 1 && board[cell] == '1')
            {
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
                cout << "  " << board[0] << "  |  " << turn << "  |  " << board[2] << endl;
                cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
                cout << "  " << board[3] << "  |  " << board[4] << "  |  " << board[5] << endl;
                cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
                cout << "  " << board[6] << "  |  " << board[7] << "  |  " << board[8] << endl;
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
            }
            else if (choice == 2 && board[cell] == '2')
            {
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
                cout << "  " << board[0] << "  |  " << board[1] << "  |  " << turn << endl;
                cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
                cout << "  " << board[3] << "  |  " << board[4] << "  |  " << board[5] << endl;
                cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
                cout << "  " << board[6] << "  |  " << board[7] << "  |  " << board[8] << endl;
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
            }
            else if (choice == 3 && board[cell] == '3')
            {
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
                cout << "  " << board[0] << "  |  " << board[1] << "  |  " << board[2] << endl;
                cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
                cout << "  " << turn << "  |  " << board[4] << "  |  " << board[5] << endl;
                cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
                cout << "  " << board[6] << "  |  " << board[7] << "  |  " << board[8] << endl;
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
            }
            else if (choice == 4 && board[cell] == '4')
            {
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
                cout << "  " << board[0] << "  |  " << board[1] << "  |  " << board[2] << endl;
                cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
                cout << "  " << board[3] << "  |  " << turn << "  |  " << board[5] << endl;
                cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
                cout << "  " << board[6] << "  |  " << board[7] << "  |  " << board[8] << endl;
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
            }
            else if (choice == 5 && board[cell] == '5')
            {
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
                cout << "  " << board[0] << "  |  " << board[1] << "  |  " << board[2] << endl;
                cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
                cout << "  " << board[3] << "  |  " << board[4] << "  |  " << turn << endl;
                cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
                cout << "  " << board[6] << "  |  " << board[7] << "  |  " << board[8] << endl;
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
            }
            else if (choice == 6 && board[cell] == '6')
            {
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
                cout << "  " << board[0] << "  |  " << board[1] << "  |  " << board[2] << endl;
                cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
                cout << "  " << board[3] << "  |  " << board[4] << "  |  " << board[5] << endl;
                cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
                cout << "  " << turn << "  |  " << board[7] << "  |  " << board[8] << endl;
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
            }
            else if (choice == 7 && board[cell] == '7')
            {
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
                cout << "  " << board[0] << "  |  " << board[1] << "  |  " << board[2] << endl;
                cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
                cout << "  " << board[3] << "  |  " << board[4] << "  |  " << board[5] << endl;
                cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
                cout << "  " << board[6] << "  |  " << turn << "  |  " << board[8] << endl;
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
            }
            else if (choice == 8 && board[cell] == '8')
            {
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
                cout << "  " << board[0] << "  |  " << board[1] << "  |  " << board[2] << endl;
                cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
                cout << "  " << board[3] << "  |  " << board[4] << "  |  " << board[5] << endl;
                cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
                cout << "  " << board[6] << "  |  " << board[7] << "  |  " << turn << endl;
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "This cell number is already used! Enter the number again.";
            }

            turn1 = '0';
            if (turn1 == 'x')
            {
                cout << "Player's 1 turn [x]: ";
            }
            else if (turn1 == '0')
            {
                cout << "Player's 2 turn [0]: ";
            }
            cin >> choice;
            cout << "enter the cell number: ";
            cin >> cell;
            if (choice == 0 && board[cell] == '0')
            {
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
                cout << "  " << turn1 << "  |  " << board[1] << "  |  " << board[2] << endl;
                cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
                cout << "  " << board[3] << "  |  " << board[4] << "  |  " << board[5] << endl;
                cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
                cout << "  " << board[6] << "  |  " << board[7] << "  |  " << board[8] << endl;
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
            }
            else if (choice == 1 && board[cell] == '1')
            {
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
                cout << "  " << board[0] << "  |  " << turn1 << "  |  " << board[2] << endl;
                cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
                cout << "  " << board[3] << "  |  " << board[4] << "  |  " << board[5] << endl;
                cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
                cout << "  " << board[6] << "  |  " << board[7] << "  |  " << board[8] << endl;
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
            }
            else if (choice == 2 && board[cell] == '2')
            {
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
                cout << "  " << board[0] << "  |  " << board[1] << "  |  " << turn1 << endl;
                cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
                cout << "  " << board[3] << "  |  " << board[4] << "  |  " << board[5] << endl;
                cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
                cout << "  " << board[6] << "  |  " << board[7] << "  |  " << board[8] << endl;
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
            }
            else if (choice == 3 && board[cell] == '3')
            {
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
                cout << "  " << board[0] << "  |  " << board[1] << "  |  " << board[2] << endl;
                cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
                cout << "  " << turn1 << "  |  " << board[4] << "  |  " << board[5] << endl;
                cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
                cout << "  " << board[6] << "  |  " << board[7] << "  |  " << board[8] << endl;
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
            }
            else if (choice == 4 && board[cell] == '4')
            {
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
                cout << "  " << board[0] << "  |  " << board[1] << "  |  " << board[2] << endl;
                cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
                cout << "  " << board[3] << "  |  " << turn1 << "  |  " << board[5] << endl;
                cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
                cout << "  " << board[6] << "  |  " << board[7] << "  |  " << board[8] << endl;
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
            }
            else if (choice == 5 && board[cell] == '5')
            {
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
                cout << "  " << board[0] << "  |  " << board[1] << "  |  " << board[2] << endl;
                cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
                cout << "  " << board[3] << "  |  " << board[4] << "  |  " << turn1 << endl;
                cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
                cout << "  " << board[6] << "  |  " << board[7] << "  |  " << board[8] << endl;
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
            }
            else if (choice == 6 && board[cell] == '6')
            {
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
                cout << "  " << board[0] << "  |  " << board[1] << "  |  " << board[2] << endl;
                cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
                cout << "  " << board[3] << "  |  " << board[4] << "  |  " << board[5] << endl;
                cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
                cout << "  " << turn1 << "  |  " << board[7] << "  |  " << board[8] << endl;
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
            }
            else if (choice == 7 && board[cell] == '7')
            {
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
                cout << "  " << board[0] << "  |  " << board[1] << "  |  " << board[2] << endl;
                cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
                cout << "  " << board[3] << "  |  " << board[4] << "  |  " << board[5] << endl;
                cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
                cout << "  " << board[6] << "  |  " << turn1 << "  |  " << board[8] << endl;
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
            }
            else if (choice == 8 && board[cell] == '8')
            {
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
                cout << "  " << board[0] << "  |  " << board[1] << "  |  " << board[2] << endl;
                cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
                cout << "  " << board[3] << "  |  " << board[4] << "  |  " << board[5] << endl;
                cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
                cout << "  " << board[6] << "  |  " << board[7] << "  |  " << turn1 << endl;
                cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "This cell number is already used! Enter the number again." << endl;
                startGame();
            }
        }
}
```

This is somehow complex. It runs but the problem is that at every player's turn, it just prints the respective 'x' or '0' at the given position but does not display the previous board with last marks.

Comment: Where/how are you storing the ongoing state of the game?  When you step through this in a debugger, where do you expect the values of the previous moves to come from?  Were those values ever stored there?  What is there?

Comment: That is the main problem... this is what i am not understanding how to store those values.

Comment: kindly run it and check what is the error plx.

Comment: I guess you could store them in an array.  For example, you could have a character array of length 9 (or a 2-dimensional array of lengths 3, if you want to get fancy) and store in each element either a space, an "x", or an "o".  Each time a move is made, update the array element to reflect the change.

Comment: `"kindly run it and check what is the error"` - Stack Overflow is not your debugger.  *You* can run your own code.

Comment: but how to update the array??

Comment: `someArray[x] = y;`  (Where `x` is the index to be updated, and `y` is the value to write to it.)  Where exactly are you stuck here?  Not to sound unhelpful, but it really seems like you could benefit from walking through some tutorials on C++.  Start with small pieces of functionality and work your way up.  It sounds like you're mainly asking for personalized help on completing your project, and I'm afraid this isn't really the venue for that.  We're happy to help with specific questions, but this is sounding pretty broad at the moment.

Comment: I am just not good at programming.. anyways thanks for ur help.. I'll try to make it better.